# How to duplicate array elements and find their sum?

Tags: php, arrays, sum

This is my code:

```
$a = -5;
$i = 0;

while ($i < 2) {
    $arr = array($a);
    $arroutput = array_sum($arr);
    $i++;
}

print_r($arroutput);
```

What I **want** is an array output like this:

```
-10
```

What I **get** is an array which only has

```
-5
```

Apologies if this is incredibly trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `$arr = array($a);` to `$arr[] = $a;`

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/759978)

```
<?php

$a = -5;
$i = 0;

while ($i < 2)
{
    $arr[] = $a;
    $arroutput = array_sum($arr);
    $i++;
}

print_r($arroutput);
?>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations! Also note that `$arroutput = array_sum($arr);` inside the loop is just nonsense.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much. I'll approve the answer as soon as my time limiter allows me to. Thanks so much!

Comment: @SahilGulati If you don't mind me asking, could you let me know what was wrong what my code, so that I can get an idea about the solution?

Comment: @n00b12345 `$arr = array($a);` here every time you are initializing an array  with in a loop. But `$arr[] = $a;` here we are keep on adding `$a` in the `$arr` array.

Answer (score 0):

Sahil's answer, for its size, it is amazingly full of bad advice.  You don't need to use a loop, an incrementing variable, nor call `array_sum()` on each iteration.  His solution is almost entirely void of "best practices".  His answer is definitely not something that you or future SO readers should be learning from.

To generate an array of duplicated elements without a loop, use [array_fill()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php).

To calculate the sum of the generated values, use [array_sum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) JUST ONCE.

You should be using this instead:

Code:  ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c1a853bc385a658c3407f2dfc3ea341b018567c8)) *first set of lines is the verbose version, the second nests one function in the other.

```
$number=-5;
$times=2;
var_export([array_sum(array_fill(0,$times,$number))]);
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => -10,
)
```

This method fills an array with elements holding the `$number` value `$times` times, finds the sum of the elements, and returns the sum as a single element array.